# How to translate this javascript code to vb.net

Tags: vb.net

It's a simple code

```
var contentHash = CryptoJS.SHA512(JSON.stringify(requestBody)).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
```

Also it's actually simpler. I think requestBody is just an empty string.

https://bittrex.github.io/api/v3#topic-Authentication

What I tried is to do

```
    Dim hasher = New System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(""))
    Dim contentHash = ExchangesClass.getString(hasher.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("")))
```

Where ExchangeClass.getString is

```
Public Shared Function getString(sigs As Byte()) As String
    Dim list = New Generic.List(Of String)

    For Each b In sigs
        Dim chunk = b.ToString("x2")
        list.Add(chunk)
    Next

    Dim result = String.Concat(list)
    Dim result2 = BitConverter.ToString(sigs).Replace("-", "").ToLower()

    Debug.Assert(result = result2)
    Return result
End Function
```

But that's sort of weird. Why would anyone want a hash of an empty string. Unless I am missing something. I do not see where requestBody is. Perhaps because I use only read only API of bittrex

Comment: First of all SHA512 and HMACSHA512 are two different things, so you can't do HMACSHA in your VB code when the original JS code only does SHA. And looking at the linked documentation you will need both of them. The SHA for ensuring the body was transferred correctly, the HMAC for authentication purposes. That also an empty body is to be hashed, is probably only for consistency reasons, so that all requests at the backend can be handled equally ...

Comment: Wait a minute. SHA512 and HMACSHA512 are different? You sure? I used that code to deal with so many other exchange

Comment: Yes, absolutely. they are different things. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm  vs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC

Comment: Oh wait a minute you are right. However, System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512 has mustInherit in vb.net. So what exactly should I do?

Comment: I'm not a vb guy, so I can't really help you with that. Just wanted to flag a basic misunderstanding ...

Comment: I see. That's where the bug is

Answer (score 0):

This code works
So

```
var contentHash = CryptoJS.SHA512(JSON.stringify(requestBody)).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
```

becomes

```
Protected Overridable Function computeSigNoHmac(content As String) As String
    Dim hasher2 = New System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed() 'create hashers based on those bytes
    Dim hashbytes = hasher2.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)) 'compute the hash and get bytes
    Dim sighash2 = BitConverter.ToString(hashbytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower() 'turn bytes into hex string (0-9a-f)
    Return sighash2
End Function
```

Also, for completion,

```
var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA512(preSign, apiSecret).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
```

Becomes

```
Protected Overridable Function computeSig(content As String, secret As String) As String
    Dim secretinBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret) 'Turn secret hex into bytes (0-9a-f)
    Dim hasher2 = New System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512(secretinBytes) 'create hashers based on those bytes
    'Dim hasher3 = New System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512(secretinBytes) 'create hashers based on those bytes
    Dim hashbytes = hasher2.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)) 'compute the hash and get bytes
    Dim sighash2 = BitConverter.ToString(hashbytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower() 'turn bytes into hex string (0-9a-f)

    Return sighash2
End Function
```